# AspxGridView Specified method is not supported. problem

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-objects, devexpress

**Bellow is my .aspx aspxGridview syntax**

```
 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            KeyFieldName="intProductCode" onrowinserted="ASPxGridView1_RowInserted">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                    <EditButton Visible="True">
                    </EditButton>
                    <NewButton Visible="True">
                    </NewButton>
                    <DeleteButton Visible="True">
                    </DeleteButton>
                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="intProductCode" FieldName="intProductCode" 
                    VisibleIndex="1">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="strProductName" FieldName="strProductName" 
                    VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="SKU" FieldName="SKU" VisibleIndex="3">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="PACK" FieldName="PACK" VisibleIndex="4">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="intQtyPerCase" FieldName="intQtyPerCase" 
                    VisibleIndex="5">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="mnyCasePrice" FieldName="mnyCasePrice" 
                    VisibleIndex="6">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="intTBQtyPerCase" 
                    FieldName="intTBQtyPerCase" VisibleIndex="7">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn Caption="bIsActive" FieldName="bIsActive" 
                    VisibleIndex="8">
                </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="intSortingOrder" 
                    FieldName="intSortingOrder" VisibleIndex="9">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="strProductAccCode" 
                    FieldName="strProductAccCode" VisibleIndex="10">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Bellow is my C# syntax :**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsPostBack != true)
            {
                BindGridView();
            }
        }

        private void BindGridView()
        {
            DB_OrderV2DataContext db = new DB_OrderV2DataContext();
            var r = from p in db.tblProductInfos
                    select p;
            ASPxGridView1.DataSource = r;
            ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void LinqServerModeDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
        {
            DB_OrderV2DataContext db = new DB_OrderV2DataContext();
            var r= from p in db.tblProductInfos
                   select p;
            e.QueryableSource = r;


        }

        protected void ASPxGridView1_RowInserted(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            DB_OrderV2DataContext db = new DB_OrderV2DataContext();


            tblProductInfo otblProductInfo = new tblProductInfo ();

            otblProductInfo.intProductCode = (db.tblProductInfos.Max(p => (int?)p.intProductCode) ?? 0) + 1;//oProductController.GenerateProductCode();
            otblProductInfo.strProductName = Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["strProductName"]);
            otblProductInfo.SKU = Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["SKU"]);
            otblProductInfo.PACK = Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["PACK"]);
            otblProductInfo.intQtyPerCase = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValues["intQtyPerCase"]);
            otblProductInfo.mnyCasePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NewValues["mnyCasePrice"]);
            otblProductInfo.intTBQtyPerCase = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValues["intTBQtyPerCase"]);
            otblProductInfo.bIsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValues["bIsActive"]);
            otblProductInfo.intSortingOrder = (db.tblProductInfos.Max(p => (int?)p.intSortingOrder) ?? 0) + 1;//oProductController.GenerateSortingOrder();

            db.tblProductInfos.InsertOnSubmit(otblProductInfo);//the InsertOnSubmit method called in the preceding code was named Add and the DeleteOnSubmit method was named Remove.
            db.SubmitChanges();
            BindGridView();
            //oProductController.InsertAndSubmit();
           // ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

**My SQL syntax**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProductInfo](
    [intProductCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [strProductName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SKU] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PACK] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [intQtyPerCase] [int] NULL,
    [mnyCasePrice] [money] NULL,
    [intTBQtyPerCase] [int] NULL,
    [bIsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [intSortingOrder] [int] NULL,
    [strProductAccCode] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblProductInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [intProductCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When i want to insert ,show me error message **Specified method is not supported.**
How to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

The "Specified Method is Not Supported" error message is shown when the ASPxGridView tries to call the Update (Insert, Delete) command of its underlying DataSource, but this command is not specified. If you cannot define this command, handle the RowUpdating (RowInserting, RowDeleting) event, update the data source manually (the e.NewValues dictionary contains input value) and finally, set the e.Cancel parameter to true and call the ASPxGridView.CancelEdit method.

Comment: will you please send some syntax.I want to insert than update,than delete.If i set e.Cancle=true on rowInserting method  then rowInserted method not work.

Comment: Indeed, the E257 example shows how these events can be used.  Why do you need to use the RowInserted event?  In your case,  it should not be raised and all the code should be implemented within the RowInserting event handler.

Comment: if you floww this advice you end up witha  dirty grid, the database has changed but the grid is not showing the new record

Comment: NO!  The grid will show the updated data.  The RowInserted event is only raised by the ASPxGridView if it uses its own logic to update data in the DB.  Since everything is done within the RowInserting event and e.Cancel is set to true, the grid does not invoke its mechamism and thus the event is not raised.  So, be sure, the approach suggested is absolutely correct.  I used it multiple times myself.  Finally, the E257 example also does not use the RowInserted event and everything works properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not plan on using the DataSource commands then you can use the Grid RowUpdating event and set e.Cancel = true then call grid.CancelEdit() method (As mentioned by DevExpress Team above. Below is an example:

```
        void grid_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your update logic here.
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.editableGrid.CancelEdit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you just ensure you want to insert or update.In your Inserting method need to write 
**e.cancle=true**

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/74138/253467.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this contain the solution what to do .How to do

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E257.aspx